# Unable to identify the mistake that generates the error message

Tags: mysql

```
var child_process = require ("child_process");

 var command = 'mysqldump --user=root --password=helloworld --databases ' + args.db_name > '~/sqldump/sqldump.sql';

        var dump = child_process.exec(command, function (err,stdout){
            if(err)
                console.log({error : err},"Error while taking the dump");

            console.log(stdout);
        });
```

getting the error :

> { error:    { [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c false    ] killed:
>   false, code: 1, signal: null, cmd: '/bin/sh -c false' } } 'Error while
>   taking the dump'

Comment: it is not a mysql error

Comment: `args.db_name > '~/sqldump/sqldump.sql'` should be `args.db_name + ' > ~/sqldump/sqldump.sql'`

Comment: Please don't post error messages in the title of your question. Use plain english and make it informative

Comment: I am sorry but I am getting this error while executing my code :                                                                          { error: { [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c false ] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null, cmd: '/bin/sh -c false' } } 'Error while taking the dump'.

Comment: You wrote that in the question, that's fine. Have you tried my fix?

Comment: yes, I did. Still not working but now getting a new error.

Comment: I am trying to access SQL on my local system and getting a error : error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Tried different things and searching for different solutions but still no progress

Comment: The solution is to use the correct username/password combination from an allowed host. If you don't find a solution to this on Google, you'll probably find nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have only a slight syntax problem due to mangling quotes and symbols:

Change

```
args.db_name > '~/sqldump/sqldump.sql'
```

to:

```
args.db_name + ' > ~/sqldump/sqldump.sql'
```